# Accessing array inside of Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, ecmascript-6

I have a functional component that renders out the object values

```
    const MovieItemDetails = (props) => {
  return <div className='item-details'>
    <div>
      <img key={props.movieDetails.id} src={`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1280${props.movieDetails.backdrop_path}`} alt={props.movieDetails.title} className='header-item-image' />
      <a href='#t' className='header-item-name'>{props.movieDetails.title}</a>
      <img src={`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/${props.movieDetails.poster_path}`} alt={props.movieDetails.title} className='header-item-poster' />
      <h2>{props.movieDetails.genres[0].name}</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
}
```

I'm trying to access the nested array as seen in the image below
 [image]

What I want is the genre name of the first array, I have tried {`props.movieDetails.genres[0].name}`

but I get 'TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined'

EDIT: full Object [image]

Comment: Add the complete movieDetails object in question instead of image please

Comment: @invrt where is 'movieDetails' key in the image?

Comment: The above object doesn't show id, title keys as well even if we assume it to be movieDetails

Comment: @CodeManiac I have added the complete object layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of referring the nested array time and again, better to extract it in const at the start and check for its value before rendering. Please see below:

```
const MovieItemDetails = (props) => {
      const {movieDetails} = {...props};
      return (movieDetails && movieDetails.genres ? <div className='item-details'>
        <div>
          <img key={movieDetails.id} src={`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1280${movieDetails.backdrop_path}`} alt={movieDetails.title} className='header-item-image' />
          <a href='#t' className='header-item-name'>{movieDetails.title}</a>
          <img src={`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/${movieDetails.poster_path}`} alt={movieDetails.title} className='header-item-poster' />
          <h2>{movieDetails.genres[0].name}</h2>
        </div>
      </div> : null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would rather suggest to call it in right way. Please have a look at the following code.

```
import React from 'react'
import Header from './Header'
import Main from './Main'
const MovieItemDetails = (props) => {
  return <div className='item-details'>
    <div>
     <img key={props.movieDetails.id} src= {`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1280${props.movieDetails.backdrop_path}`} alt= {props.movieDetails.title} className='header-item-image' />
     <a href='#t' className='header-item-name'>{props.movieDetails.title}</a>
     <img src={`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/${props.movieDetails.poster_path}`} alt={props.movieDetails.title} className='header-item-poster' />
     <h2>{props.movieDetails.genres[0].name}</h2>
   </div>
  </div>
}
const movieDetails = {
  id: 1,
  title: 'Movie',
  genres : [
    {id: 0, name : 'Songs'}
  ]
}
const App = () => (
  <div>
    <MovieItemDetails movieDetails={movieDetails}  />
    {MovieItemDetails({movieDetails})}
 </div>
)
```

export default App